# Android page curl of a view

Tags: android, page-curl

All the code that is available for implementing page curl in android uses a fixed set of images to implement the curl. Could anyone please tell me a way to implement page curl on a linear layout(consisting of several text views, a few buttons and dynamic contents)?

Comment: I've tried the code from the following links:https://github.com/harism/android_page_curl/ http://code.google.com/p/android-page-curl/

Comment: I'd suggest using a screenshot of the current view and then do a page curl on that, so you'll need to swap the real view with the screenshot and then do the page curl.

Comment: Is real response view convert and then capture screenshot and then display to page curl is suggestible or is any other for better.please help replay me